# Eclipse Deployment - Field Level Security and Profiles - Social Post Layout Error

Tags: deployment, eclipse

I 've been trying to deploy everything from one Sandbox to another through Eclipse (Force.com installation) Tool. I have been given an extract from Salesforce Helpdesk

'https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip'

Eclipse is able to get some of the information but not all of them at once.
When I include all the metadata, it errors in Social-Post layout and also in all the profiles ( shows dependency with the Social Post Layout)

I would need expert advice on using eclipse or any other deployment methodology in salesforce.

Thanks & Regards,
Poonam

Answer (score 0):

We have also had some issues with the Social Post Layout etc.
We eventually decided not to include those components in the deploy. For us that fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks!! I need to know how do you go about the profiles deployment. And if you go by the change set, then profiles would be effective for those components which are added along with the profile whilst deploying. As our org has outsourced the salesfore dev to some other vendor, we don't know what they are changing.